# PostgreSQL inserting list of objects into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently learning PostgreSQL and have hit a wall when it comes to stored procedures.

I have an order table with these columns:

```
OrderId
OrderStatus
OrderTime
```

I also have an order line table

```
OrderId
OrderLineId
OrderLineAmount
OrderLineCost
```

I am trying to write a stored procedure which would create an order and then insert a list of order lines into the second table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.createcustomerorder(
_orderstatus integer, 
_ordertimestamp timestamp)
RETURNS int4 AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE 
    last_id int4;
  BEGIN

  INSERT INTO "Order"
    (orderstatus, ordertimestamp)
    VALUES(_orderstatus, _ordertimestamp)
    RETURNING orderid INTO last_id;
RETURN last_id;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am finding it difficult for figure out how I can pass in the parameters, and then how to do the actual insert.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to pass a list of records to a function.

Using the simple table for examples, you can to adapt it to your schema:

```
create table t(id serial primary key, x int, y text);
```

**JSON**

```
create function foo_j(data JSON) returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
  insert into t(x, y)
  select (d->>'x')::int, (d->>'y')::text
  from json_array_elements(data) as d;
  return;
end $$;
```

Usage:

```
select foo_j('[{"x": 1, "y": "a"}, {"x": 2, "y": "b"}]');
```

**Array**

To use the array you need to declare the type for its elements. It will contains variable fields for your table, in our example all except id:

```
create type t_data as (x int, y text);

create function foo_a(data t_data[]) returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
  insert into t(x, y)
  select d.x, d.y
  from unnest(data) as d;
  return;
end $$;
```

Usage:

```
select foo_a(array[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]::t_data[]);
```

**Variadic**

Almost same but difference in the function declaration and its call:

```
create function foo_v(variadic data t_data[]) returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
  insert into t(x, y)
  select d.x, d.y
  from unnest(data) as d;
  return;
end $$;
```

Usage:

```
select foo_v((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'));
```

Documentation:

- [JSON type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)
- [Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)
- [Variadic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

Comment: Might get overseen: better also write the `create type t_data as (x int, y text);` for the `variadic` block.